# Full davening audio or video

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, chinuch-education, recording

I have a friend who struggles greatly with Hebrew reading but is equally keen to learn how to daven properly. Where can I find audio or video recordings of the davening (all parts)?

I imagine there would be a significant demand for a comprehensive library of the davening in different nuscha'ot for teaching purposes.

Comment: [Virtual Cantor](http://www.virtualcantor.com/) seems to skip the parts not read aloud by the cantor...

Comment: I think your premise is flawed. I think you will only find content for groups such as chabad, who put a focus on outreach.  I think you should be more specific as to which nusach you are interested in.

Comment: just record yourself oneday

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you can read you can daven!

Comment: I haven't investigated, but this looks promising: http://mechonhadar.org/tefillah-music

Answer (score 1):

Well...  There are a few places where you can get *much* of davening, and there are many places where you can get *some* of davening, but there is no place where you can get *all* of davening.  I'm trying to create such a place.  I will not succeed, but hopefully over time there will be a solid collection of resources.  For now, though, I would recommend [Offtonic Nusach Resources](http://offtonic.com/nusach/nusach.html).  Browse the sites there; they are categorized generally by service and ranked within that service based on the quality and quantity of their offerings.  They include resources from around the world, though mostly only in languages that I can sorta understand!  I am also creating NusachDB, which categorizes different melodies for each section of each service, but I haven't gotten very far yet; the wedding service, at least, has quite a few different melodies.